# iOS 8 custom keyboard dismiss (from textfield, etc)

Tags: keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

In new iOS 8 custom keyboard extension, we can go to next keyboard by this code.

```
[self advanceToNextInputMode];
```

How can I dismiss custom keyboard? (not hide, not go to next keyboard). 
Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: what happened to the good-old `resignFirstResponder` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UIInputViewController`'s `dismissKeyboard` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below,

**Objective-C:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```